# "docker images" shows image, "docker rmi" says "no such image" or "reference does not exist"

Tags: linux, docker

In some reasons I can't delete docker image.
Here is output

OS version:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.12.13-300.fc26.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 14 16:00:38 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 20:05:40 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 20:06:58 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false`
```

I have no any container:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

and two images that I want to delete:

```
$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gcc                 7.1.0               855a4f4d1cd9        2 months ago        1.64GB
hello-world         latest              1815c82652c0        3 months ago        1.84kB
```

My attempts:

```
$ docker rmi -f gcc:7.1.0
Error response from daemon: No such image: gcc:7.1.0

$ docker rmi -f 855a4f4d1cd9
Error response from daemon: reference does not exist

$ docker rmi -f hello-world:latest 
Error response from daemon: No such image: hello-world:latest

$ docker rmi -f 1815c82652c0
Error response from daemon: reference does not exist44
```

What the reason could be and how can I delete those images?

Comment: (For search-engine completeness) This same happened to me after updated from docker-engine (ver. 1.13.x) to a newer docker CE version(17.06.02-ce). Tarun Lalwani answer (stop -> sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker -> start) fixed it too.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This means that your docker state is corrupted and you need clear the complete state

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo service docker start
```

This will start docker fresh without any existing data. Try pulling deleting the image after this and see if all works. If it doesn't then there is some issue that needs to be looked into

Comment: I had this issue after upgrading from 1.12.6 to 18.02.... your solution fixed the problem ("sudo systemctl stop docker" on systemd )

Comment: this did it for me , though know what you're doing , this will delete everything from docker , networks , swarms , stacks , etc.

Comment: after running these commands, now docker doesn't work anymore :) 
I get `Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp: no such file or directory`

Comment: You should reinstall docker packages

Answer (score 32):

Try first a [**`docker image prune`**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) or even `docker image prune -a`, to remove any image unused/not associated to at least one container.

If those are still listed, restart your docker daemon.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.
I'v also tried to run `docker inspect hello-world` and got `Error: No such object: hello-world`

Comment: @RidgeA But does `docker image prune -a` return any error message? Are those images still present after restarting the docker daemon.

Comment: yes they are still there. I'v even restarted PC :( 

`docker image prune -a
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B`

Comment: @RidgeA Do you see a `/var/lib/docker/images` on your Linux host?

Comment: no. `ls /var/lib/docker/ --> containers  devicemapper  image  network  plugins  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes`

Comment: yes ! `docker image prune -a` finally cleaned all the extra space taken by images otherwise impossible to `rmi`

Answer (score 11):

To avoid deleting all of your docker data and starting from scratch, you can also attempt to manually clean up the broken references by matching the bad image references to the files in `/var/lib/docker/image/devicemapper/imagedb/content/sha256`. Once the corresponding file is deleted there, it will no longer show up in subsequent calls to `docker images`, and no daemon restarts are required.

Comment: The path may be at ```/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256```